# About semiclassical analysis and resource request

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, semiclassical-analysis

I was going through pseudodifferential operators when I got to know about "Semiclassical Analysis". Looking at some resources, I think this subject is mostly (or exactly) related to Mathematics for physics (or maybe I am wrong). I want to learn it and hence need some suggestions about where should I start from.

Some questions:

1. Should I already need some knowledge of college Physics to start it?
2. Are there good books and notes on it which covers from basics (meaning that it also includes the physics point of view)?
3. If any theory from physics is needed, what are the exact topics and references for them?

FYI, I have already done courses in analysis (Real (till Measure theory), Complex, Functional), know some Differential geometry and Topology (if it helps).